Unexpected server response: 404 in a simple PHP webserver
I'm trying to build a simple PHP WebSocket application using the Rachet library.
I have everything set up on a test server and the code seems to be working fine locally (on the same machine, but using only 'ws' instead 'wss').
Here's the relevant part of my code:
// ... 
// Create the event loop
$loop = LoopFactory::create();

$webSock = new Reactor('127.0.0.1:8080', $loop);

// SSL/TLS configuration
$sslContext = [
    'local_cert' => '<HIDDEN_BUT_PATH_IS_CORRECT>', 
    'local_pk'   => '<HIDDEN_BUT_PATH_IS_CORRECT>',
    'allow_self_signed' => false, // Set to true only for testing purposes
    'verify_peer' => false,        // Set to true if you need to verify peer certificate
];

// Create the IoServer with the WebSocket and HTTP server
$server = new IoServer(
  new HttpServer(
    new WsServer(
      new MyWebSocketApp()
    )
  ),
  $secureWebSock,
  $loop
);

echo "Secure WebSocket server started on port 8080 (wss://)".PHP_EOL;
// ...

Also, I'm able to send messages to the websocket in same machine using :
use WebSocket\Client;
// ...
$socket_uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080";
$client = new Client($socket_uri);
$client->send("{$message}");
$client->disconnect();
// ...

Now, for clients, the primary issue is that the server uses Sucuri, which prevents me from using port 8080.
As a workaround, I've added the following rule to the Apache web server:
# mysite.url.conf
# ...
<Location /websocket>
        ProxyPass "wss://127.0.0.1:8080"
        ProxyPassReverse "wss://127.0.0.1:8080"
</Location>
# ...

But an issue occurs when attempting to test the WebSocket connection using wscat:
wscat -c wss://mysite.url/websocket
error: Unexpected server response: 404

here are the apache version and installed proxy modules.
$ httpd -v 
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (Rocky Linux) 
Server built: Aug 5 2024 00:00:00 
$httpd -M | grep proxy 
proxy_module (shared) 
proxy_ajp_module (shared) 
proxy_balancer_module (shared) 
proxy_connect_module (shared) 
proxy_express_module (shared) 
proxy_fcgi_module (shared) 
proxy_fdpass_module (shared) 
proxy_ftp_module (shared) 
proxy_hcheck_module (shared) 
proxy_scgi_module (shared) 
proxy_uwsgi_module (shared) 
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared) 
proxy_http2_module (shared)

What am I doing wrong? Or I missed something?

To proxy websocket connections through Apache you should try https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

@ADyson, Thanks for you reply but just to make sure that I understand you correctly, I'm currently using mod_proxy_wstunnel in .conf lines:
<Location /websocket>
ProxyPass "wss://127.0.0.1:8080"
ProxyPassReverse "wss://127.0.0.1:8080"

Or I'm wrong?

Well that's the config, but did you actually install the Apache module called mod_proxy_wstunnel?

Note that it also says that since Apache 2.4.47, mod_proxy_http can also handle this functionality instead. But you haven't stated your Apache version and it's unclear whether you've got the mod_proxy_http module installed or not, either.

Sorry, here are the apache version and installed proxy modules.
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (Rocky Linux)
Server built:   Aug  5 2024 00:00:00
$httpd -M | grep proxy
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)
proxy_express_module (shared)
proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_hcheck_module (shared)
proxy_scgi_module (shared)
proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
proxy_http2_module (shared)

Thanks, that's clearer. I added it to the question for you. Hopefully someone with detailed knowledge of this module and settings will be able to spot if you've done anything specifically wrong

This 404 might be an index or error page not found; I'd try: 'allow_self_signed' => true.
